# global $product is null in functions.php file

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm looking at getting the current displayed product to move the bundles location but for some reason `global $product` is `null`. I need to know if bundles exists or else it my action change causes an error and the product stop its execution. How can I get the current product within `functions.php`?

Below is my functions.php code:

```
if (class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) && class_exists('WC_Bundles')) {

    // Abort if no bundle items.
    global $product;
    if (!$product || empty($product->get_bundled_items()))
          return;

    // Move product bundles above the tabs.
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_bundle_add_to_cart', 'wc_pb_template_add_to_cart' );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'wc_pb_template_add_to_cart', 0 );

}
```

Comment: why do you need to set this as a global?

Comment: You need to set this code in a hooked function related to the single product page, to get the current `WC_Product` object. Without that you will never get anything.